# Minimal number of edges removed to make a graph triangle free

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

I'm interested in finding an upper bound on the expected value of the minimal number of edges one needs to remove from a random graph $G_{n,p}$ (where each edge appears with probability $p$) in order to make it triangle free.
Particularly, I would really be happy if it was of size less than $\Theta(pn^2)$. 
Has anyone came across something like this?

Comment: To have some better direction, the graph can be assumed to be simple?

Comment: Yes, I'm only interested in simple graphs.

Comment: There are several papers related to this problem, if you are interested. However, it seems that the size could be as high as $p*n^2$ asymptotically, but can be bounded around that. Just note for example, that in the graph $K_n$, you would've have to delete about half of the edges in order to reach a triangle-free graph(!).

Comment: Is there a specific range of $p$ that you interested in? For instance, if $p \ll n^{-5/6}$, then w.h.p. all triangles are edge-disjoint. In this case, the number of edges to be deleted is $O_p(n^3p^3),$ which is much smaller than $n^2p$.

Comment: That's very much true, you might also be interested in reading [this paper](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~conlond/RemSurvey.pdf), especially from part 5 and onwards (page 21).

Comment: This article http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4375 of Boham has a result similar. It starts with a $K_n$ and then begins to remove edges until obtain a triangle free graph. Maybe you can found something interesting..